# Is it possible to detect a download before the actual download has started in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, detection

I develope a Chrome extension. I want to detect a download before the actual download has started. There is a [chrome.downloads](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) API but all events are fired too late. There is also a [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) with a lot events. Sadly the data provided by those events didn't help me to detect a download (request). Is there any possibility to detect a download BEFORE chrome already downloads a file?

Comment: There's no other methods. BTW how have you tried it with `webRequest`? Have you analyzed the request/response headers?

Comment: chrome.download API cannot (should not) block downloading. btw, why you want to detect downloading?